# $(document).on('click' stores up values

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
$(document).on("click", ".exercise", function() {
  var clickedBtnID = $(this).attr('id'); // or var clickedBtnID = this.id
  var classElem = $(this).attr('class')
  var deleteBtn = document.getElementById('deleteExBtn');

  deleteBtn.addEventListener('click', e => {
    if (classElem.includes('plannedEx') == true) {
      deletePlannedExercise(clickedBtnID);
      deactivateDetailContainer();
      console.log("Du slettet planlagt økt")
    } else if (classElem.includes('doneEx') == true) {
      deleteDoneExercise(clickedBtnID);
      deletePlannedExercise(clickedBtnID);
      deactivateDetailContainer();
      console.log("Du slettet gjennomført økt")
    }
  })
  console.log(classElem.includes('plannedEx'))
  console.log(classElem.includes('doneEx'))
});
```

When I click on an element that includes the class ".exercise" it returns the right classes in the "classElem" variable. But if I click on multiple elements with the class ".exercise" and then click on the delete button it deletes all the elements with the class ".exercise". I want it only to delete the last element that was clicked. Thanks for any answers.

Comment: Please also post all of the relevant HTML markups also.

Comment: the code provided isn't enough to solve your issue, but I'd bet that the problem arise from the listener you are creating everytime a click is done on a element with `.exercise` class